# get the client IP and computer's username

Tags: c#, wpf

```
   user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

I am using it to get the information of the user who attempts to delete a file I leave in a directory, but my computer and his are both clients, so the user always return the name of my computer. Could you tell me how to resolve this problem ?

[More explanation: I am making an application to monitor my folder's specific file, my computer is a client computer and his is also a client, I try to monitor the file server's public place e.g \192.168.1.15\Public\myfolder, I would like to get any accesses from other clients who may attempt to delete one of my files in that folder.] Thank you for any idea and solutions you offer.

Comment: Please clarify the question, explain the client-server scenario and running applications. Its quite hard to understand what you want to achieve and what are the problems achieving it.

Comment: better way to use the diffrent logins per user that will help you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Dns.GetHostName()` from `System.Net` namespace to get the host name of the computer, or use `Environment.MachineName` for the machine name.

To get the current user name, use `Environment.UserName`.

Answer (score 0):

Could this help you ? seems very similar to your problem. 
It uses FileSystemWatcher to monitor the folder and reads info on the user from the  Event Log.

[Get username of an accessed file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861512/get-username-of-an-accesed-file)