# Checking who edited my file

Tags: c#, io, filesystems, filesystemwatcher, user-management

There is file named `status.html` which is used as a loadbalancer between WFE's on SharePoint servers. My query is I want to come up with a script or a mechanism that will trigger a mail as soon as this file is edited by someone.
Is it possible?

In my research I have found this script:

```
$ACL = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
$AccessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule("domain\seitconsult","Modify","success")
$ACL.SetAuditRule($AccessRule)
$ACL | Set-Acl "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
```

But I'm not sure if that will work. Also, how can trigger an email using this script?

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to achieve your goal:

1. Attach a "send an e-mail" task to the event in question:

   1. Open the Event Viewer (`eventvwr.msc`) and select an event you want to be notified about.
   2. Click *Action → Attach Task To This Event…*
   3. Step through the wizard and select *Send an e-mail* in the *Action* section.
   4. Fill in the details and finish the wizard.

   See [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2010/06/16/getting-event-log-contents-by-email-on-an-event-log-trigger.aspx) for more information.
2. Set up a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

   ```
   $folder = 'C:\your\html\folder'
   $file   = 'status.html'

   $from    = 'monitor@example.com'
   $to      = 'you@example.com'
   $subject = "$file was modified"

   $monitor = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $file -Property @{
     IncludeSubdirectories = $false
     NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
   }

   Register-ObjectEvent $monitor Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action {
     $name   = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
     $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($name)
     $msg    = $reader.ReadToEnd()
     Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $msg
     $reader.Close()
   }
   ```

   However, since the `NotifyFilters` don't include the username you need to extract that from the respective audit event in the eventlog as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861598/1630171).

   The watcher can be removed via its source identifier:

   ```
   Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileChanged
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. The C# code that you have referred to, can your please let me know how can i run it? I mean on the servers where I will implement that doesn't have C# compiler. Also, will the above power shell code generate an event in event viewer? Please provide your comments.

Comment: @Lilly123 You'll need to translate the C# code to PowerShell (use `Get-EventLog`). And no, the above code won't generate eventlog entries. If you enable auditing (which you'll need to do in order to get the information who modified the file) that will already create eventlog records.